# Airflow initdb with mysql as backend is not working

Tags: mysql, airflow, python-3.7

when I initialize airflow using mysql as backend  I see below error

> ```
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
> ```
>
> line 453, in connect
>           return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 80,
>   in Connect
>           from MySQLdb.connections import Connection
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line
>   36
>           raise errorclass, errorvalue
>                           ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
I tried re-installing mysql-python and pymysql still its same 

airflow initdb
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:627: DeprecationWarning: You have two airflow.cfg files: /home/airflow/airflow/airflow.cfg and /home/airflow/airflow.cfg. Airflow used to look at ~/airflow/airflow.cfg, even when AIRFLOW_HOME was set to a different value. Airflow will now only read /home/airflow/airflow.cfg, and you should remove the other file
  category=DeprecationWarning,
[2019-09-24 12:10:32,310] {settings.py:213} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=15403
[2019-09-24 12:10:32,508] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
DB: mysql://airdba:***@host/airflow_main
[2019-09-24 12:10:32,820] {db.py:369} INFO - Creating tables
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 1102, in initdb
    db.initdb(settings.RBAC)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 106, in initdb
    upgradedb()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 377, in upgradedb
    command.upgrade(config, 'heads')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 298, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 489, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 98, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 173, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 92, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 78, in run_migrations_online
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2206, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 103, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2306, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2275, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 303, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 760, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 453, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 80, in Connect
    from MySQLdb.connections import Connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 453, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 80, in Connect
    from MySQLdb.connections import Connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

removed mysql-python module and forced airflow to use pymysql.
changed connection string in airflow.cfg

sql_alchemy_conn = mysql+pymysql://user:password@server/dbname

Comment: how did you configured MySQL with airflow? I am facing some issues